# How can I use a button to change an image AND play a sound?

Tags: java, android, audio, onclick, imageview

I am new here and I have been looking for a way to have my app play a sound AND change the image in the background when I click a button.
The app is very simple it has a relative layout with an image and a button.
I have made it to play the sound but it doesn't change the image on the screen.

I found how to change the image on the screen and how to play the sound but I can't get it to do both on the same button click.

here's is my code for layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="us.xago.chtmpier.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/pier"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/alfredo"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/alfredo"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

     <Button
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="CHTM PIER"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

and the java

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ImageView alfredo;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         alfredo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.alfredo);
         //set invisible
         alfredo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         alfredo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
              //show image on the center of screen
              //set image
              alfredo.setImageResource(R.drawable.alfredo);
             // set visible
             alfredo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }
       });

     Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

      alfredo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
              //show image on the center of screen
             //set image
             // set visible
             alfredo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         }
      });
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chtmpier);
        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
            }
        });
      }
 }
```

Comment: Just as a general tip, you should probably give your variables slightly clearer names. Usually, this starts with a prefix, like `btn` for `Buttons`.

Comment: you are new here?? thats why your english is so bad

Comment: thanks for your comments! I am new here and I am just learning to code. I try to copy and understad others code but this one was hard for me. Sorry about my english I'll try to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  simplest way is to reuse your listener, so you have to store it in a variable. After that you can reuse your listener on your button listener.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView alfredo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alfredo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.alfredo);
        //set invisible
        alfredo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        final OnClickListener changeImage = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //show image on the center of screen
                //set image
                alfredo.setImageResource(R.drawable.alfredo);
                // set visible
                alfredo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        alfredo.setOnClickListener(changeImage);

        Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chtmpier);
        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
                changeImage.onClick(v);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write whatever you want to be executed inside the Listener of the Button. In this case, both things, the image visibility and the music playing

```
// Search and initialize ImageView state
alfredo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.alfredo);
alfredo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Create Player
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chtmpier);

// Search and initialize Button listener
Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        /* This will be executed when the button is pressed  */
        // Show picture
        alfredo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Play music
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To change an `ImageView` and play a sound with a `Button`, just use a `Button.setOnClickListener()`. You could do something like this, using the variables you have created in your question:

```
// Initializes the MediaPlayer to play the sound
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chtmpier); 

one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Changes the image to another one
        alfredo.setImageResource(R.drawable.alfredo); // Replace with whatever image
        // Ensures it is visible
        alfredo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Plays the sound
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why is `mp` a `final` variable ? Why do you create it everytime the `Button` is pressed ?

Comment: True, I don't know why I put that. I edited my answer (everyone's is basically the same at this point).

Comment: You stil create it everytime it's pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is pretty simple your code should be something like this

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     ImageView alfredo;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         alfredo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.alfredo);

         final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chtmpier);
         Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                  //show image on the center of screen
                  //set image
                  alfredo.setImageResource(R.drawable.alfredo);
                  mp.start();

               }
           });  
      }
 }
```